# PmPRO Wordpress plugin bug for reseting password

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a problem with the PaidMembership Pro plugin for WordPress. When I click on "reset password," it first displays a page where I need to enter my email to receive a message with a reset password link that contains a 'key' required to reset the password along with the username. The first issue is that in the JavaScript file that manages the PmPro plugin, there are several switch cases, but it only accepts the first switch case. In that case, if the input is empty, it adds the "disabled" value to the submit button. Okay, I've solved that part without any issues. However, the next part of the problem is that when the request is processed, I receive a "302 Found" response for the reset password, and in the preview, I have all the data I should have. The second request is for an automatic login, which returns a "200 OK," but it contains a preview with "invalid key." So, when I try to log in with the new password, it doesn't work, and I'm still stuck with the old password.

I tried to reset my password using the PmPro plugin on my WordPress website, but I was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

May help, not the outcome I expected from a premium plugin service. If nothing else it explains some errors.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/pmpro-password-reset/